# Ubuntu box crashes quite often

Tags: ubuntu

I have a ubuntu 11.04 box running 24/7. It started to crash any couple of days recently.
I checked in kern.log, dmesg... but did not find anything there. 
Is there a specific place where shutdown reason (temperature, or whatever) are logged ?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have monitoring for you server?

Actually, my answer to this would be: Please add monitoring for your server if you do not have. You should have at least: cpu load, cpu temp, disk usage, disk temp, disk IO, NIC traffic.

Just chose one you can easily install, maintain.
Any or a combination of these would work (not a complete list): mrtg, cacti, zenoss, nagios etc.; with proper plugins, snmp or rrd scripts.

Check the charts for clues after a crash happens.

Comment: I do not have monitoring as until now there was not much running on this machine, but I'll install a couple of those, thanks.

Comment: I have added monitoring to my routine of installing a server. The time spent is minimum in comparison to the benefits if you need to investigate or to troubleshot some random problem.

Comment: without installing dedicated monitoring tools, does ubuntu provide some stuff out of the box ?

Comment: asa far as i know none that can easily display charts or data.

Comment: Go for something like `Zabbix`. Easy to install and get started with

Answer (score 0):

> I have a unbuntu 11.04 box running 24/7 for something like 2 years now

You do realize this is impossible, right ?

Either it's not 2 years, or you upgraded it.

CHeck the upgrade logs for any issues.

Comment: Sorry, typo I'll update my post. Obviously I updated it several months ago. I just meant the hardware is running since 2 years. Sorry for this.